# how to implement ng2-dragula in angular 2

Tags: html, angular

how to implement ng2-dragula in angular 2.

My code is shared below,

****viewer.component.ts****

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import 'rxjs/Rx';

import { ImageViewerService } from '../services/http.services';

import { Dragula,DragulaService } from 'ng2-dragula/ng2-dragula';


@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,

    selector: 'viewer',

    directives: [Dragula],

    viewProviders: [DragulaService],

    providers: [ImageViewerService, DragulaService],

    templateUrl: 'viewer.component.html',

})
export class ViewerComponent {

    @Output() click = new EventEmitter();

    http: Http;

    url: string;

    obj: any;

    getData: string;

    postData: string;

    users: any;

    firtsImageToBind: any;

    tile: number;

    tableVisible: boolean;

    status: { isopen: boolean } = { isopen: false };

    localImageViewerService: ImageViewerService;

    localDragulaService: DragulaService;

    constructor(http: Http, imageViewerService: ImageViewerService, 
localDragulaService: DragulaService) {

        this.users = [1];

        this.http = http;

        this.localImageViewerService = imageViewerService;

        this.localDragulaService = localDragulaService;

        this.imageReceivedFromWebAPI();


    }
```

Comment: Have you set the `NgModule` correctly? what does `viewer.component.html` look like?

Oh and your constructor should not be used for doing data calls.  Use `ngOnInit`

Did you following the setup guide on GitHub ? https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula

Comment: yes, I followed that too.but that look like incomplete.

Comment: My requirement is to implement if I drag a image in one view-port(div) ,then again trying to drag another image into same view-port(div)

Comment: that time the already available image should replace.

Comment: Please provide any solution..

Comment: Post your module and viewer.component.html

Comment: import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DragulaModule } from 'ng2-dragula/ng2-dragula'; //THIS IS NEW***

Comment: /* App component and routing */
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { routing } from './app.route';

/*Components*/
import { ViewerComponent } from './viewer/viewer.component';
import { MenuComponent } from './menu/menu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { PatientComponent }  from './patient/patient.component';

Comment: @NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        JsonpModule,
        routing,
        DragulaModule

    ],
    exports: [AppComponent],
    declarations: [AppComponent, HomeComponent, MenuComponent, PatientComponent, ViewerComponent],
    providers: [Title],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})


export class AppModule { }

Comment: <div class="image_viewer">
        <!--<div>-->
        <div class='viewer_section' [dragula]='"first-bag"' *ngFor="let user of users" [ngClass]="{'column-2x1': tile===2,'column-2x2': tile===4 ||tile===3}">

Comment: <img src="{{firtsImageToBind}}" class="imagepics" alt="loading..." />
            <div class="top_left_corner_data">

            </div>
            <div class="top_right_corner_data">

            </div>
            <div class="bottom_left_corner_data">

            </div>
            <div class="bottom_right_corner_data">

            </div>

        </div>
        <!--</div>-->
    </div>

Comment: The above code are my app.module and viewer.component.html respectivily

Answer (score 1):

Ok so a quick example showing how to implement `dragula` into `Angular2` project first install via npm:

```
npm install ng2-dragula dragula --save
```

Next import into module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {DragulaModule} from 'ng2-dragula/ng2-dragula'; // Here

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    DragulaModule, // Here
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Inside `app.component.html` you do this.

```
<div>
    <div class='wrapper'>
      <div class='container' [dragula]='"first-bag"'>
        <div>You can move these elements between these two containers</div>
        <div>Moving them anywhere else isn't quite possible</div>
        <div>There's also the possibility of moving elements around in the same container, changing their position</div>
      </div>
      <div class='container' [dragula]='"first-bag"'>
        <div>This is the default use case. You only need to specify the containers you want to use</div>
        <div>More interactive use cases lie ahead</div>
        <div>Make sure to check out the <a href='https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula#readme'>documentation on GitHub!</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

run the project, and you'll be able to drag the text up and down i.e changing its order.

Example specified above is from [dragula github page.](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula)